# Ícone ao lado do input

Tags: css, font-awesome

Quero criar uma página pra rodar no captive portal, e gostei bastante dos inputs da página de login do site King Debrid, mas ela usa Bootstrap. Queria o mesmo efeito, porém sem o uso do Bootstrap.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Você tentou fazer de alguma forma?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  border:1px solid #C7C7C7;
}

i{
  background: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/2171/kiwi/32/admin.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="text"]{
  line-height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 343px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <i></i>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```